# Firestore rules & custom claims

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to make my project more secure

I have multiple custom claims: super admin, content admin, user admin
I would like these to be able to update, delete, write and read

I would also like authenticated users to be able to *read, write and update* and non authenticated users to *read*

How would I do this in firebase rules?

I have tried reading thru the documentation but I don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give any detail on how you define the "Admin" Custom Claims, but by making the assumption that you assign different "Admin" claims (e.g. `superAdmin`, `contentAdmin`, etc.), each one with a value of `true`, something along the following lines should do the trick:

```
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      
    function isAdmin() {
        return request.auth.token.superAdmin == true ||
               request.auth.token.contentAdmin == true ||
               request.auth.token.userAdmin == true;
    }
    
    function isAuthenticated() {
        return request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    match /collection/{docId} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow create, update: if isAuthenticated() || isAdmin();
        allow delete: if isAdmin();
    }

  }

}
```

---

I would suggest you watch the following official video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ