# Firestore rules aren't working and are preventing authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

unfortunately, we're not using the Firebase authentication system, we have our username and password. We want to implement the following rules:

We want to give Firebase functions and google cloud functions full access to all the collections, so if the source of the request is the project id `project-example`, then let the request pass through.

We want to implement the following rules for everyone else:

We have multiple collections and the document name usually is the same as the document id `doc.id` in most collections

let's take the following 2 collections as an example

`/users/xas1234`

```
 {
   "id", "xas1234"
   "username": "foo",
   "password": "bar"
}
```

`/tasks/xas1234`

```
 {
   "id", "xas1234"
   "title": "foo",
   "description": "bar"
}
```

What we want to do is to have a firestore rule to check if the `username` and `password` sent by the user match the username and password in firestore then give the user read and write access to `/user/xas1234` and `/tasks/xas1234`, so give the user access to the documents which hold his id

one last condition is that the admins are stored in a `admins/x1234abc`

```
{
  "id": "x123aa",
  "username": "john",
  "password": "foobar"
}
```

If the credentials sent match the admin's credentials, then the admin has to have access to everything because the admin needs to add, and remove users and so on.

So an unauthenticated user should only be able to authenticate against the credentials stored in the `users` table.

I've tried many many rules but even the basic ones, like the one below, aren't working

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /{document=**}/user/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.username == resource.data.username && request.auth.password == resource.data.password;
    }
  }
}
```

I guess the main issue is the Flutter application

```
 await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("user")
                        .where("username", isEqualTo: usernameCtrl.text.trim())
                        .limit(1)
                        .get();
```

Since you usually to a `where` clause on a single field, you won't end up having the username and the password in a single request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we're not using the Firebase authentication system

If you're not signing the user in to Firebase Authentication, the `request.auth` variable in your security rules is going to be `null` and this rule will always reject access:

```
if request.auth.username == resource.data.username
```

To make this work, you will have to sign the user in to Firebase Authentication. There is no other way to populate the `request.auth` variable in your security rules check.

Note that you **can** build your own username/password sign-in provider as shown in the documentation on [custom sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/custom-auth), and there's even an [example of username/password sign-in](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/username-password-auth).

---

The only alternative without signing the user into Firebase Authentication, is to pass the information in another way. The other two options for passing data to the security rules are:

- As part of the path of the data that you're accessing.
- As part of the `request.resource.data()` for write operations.

Since your rule applies to both reads and writes, that second option can't be applied. So that leaves only passing the information in the path to the data, e.g.

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("user")
    .document("myUsername") // 
    .collection("password")
    .document("myPassword") // 
    .get();
```

So on the lines I've marked you'd pass the username and password, and then in your database you can either check in your security rules - or you can ensure documents only exist for valid username/password combinations.

Comment: Ok thank you, will try that. Is there a flutter implementation of the custom firebase sign in or do I create a nodejs function and call that function?

The second question is ` .collection("password")`, is it a typo? did you mean the user collection or are you suggesting I create a collection for passwords?

Comment: 1) You need a server to mint custom tokens. If that was possible inside your Flutter app, then anyone could mint whatever token they want - which would be highly insecure. --- 2) Not a typo: I chose to model with a collection for password here. You can also use a single document ID for username+password: `.document("myUsername_myPassword")` if that fits your use-case better.

Comment: Ok, after authentication, how do I give users access to other collections? The flutter devs call firestore directly from flutter, so if I check `request.auth.username`, would that be set, or how to send the token?  Or should I write a cloud function for all the calls and refactor the code to use the cloud functions instead of talking to the database directly?

Comment: Once you sign in to Firebase Authentication, the `request.auth` is automatically set to the token of that user. So if you have a `username` claim in the custom token you mint, that'd be available as `request.auth.token.username` in the rules. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69530676/how-to-access-custom-claims-inside-cloud-firestore-rules

Comment: Ok, I'm working on it and testing it, I upvoted this, and I'll accept this answer and close the question in a few days just to make sure that it works as expected. I have two questions: 1) Do Cloud functions deployed on GCP need to be authenticated? 2) Using this method, can you let the user sign in forever? or should I refresh the token? Mobile users don't like to keep signing in unless it's something like a banking application, so wondering how to handle very very long sessions

Comment: 1) Cloud Functions use administrative credentials to access the project, and bypass security rules. 2) ID tokens refresh automatically iirc.

Comment: accepting this answer because it works great, but flutter don't work great apparently with this method, so I asked [this separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75972018/flutter-how-to-authenticate-firestore-using-signinwithcustomtoken-nodejs-fir), hopefully some flutter dev can help out